# draw a filled up circle

Tags: qt

I've written a function that must draw a filled up black circle on my graphicsscene. The function draws a black lined circle but not filled up?  This is my function:

```
void World::damage(int x, int y)
{
    QPainter painter(&worldImage);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
    painter.drawArc(x,y,150,50,0,16*360);
    item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(worldImage));
    this->addItem(item);

}
```

Comment: For the record, before drawing the circle use `painter.setPen()` to set the shape *border* style/color and `painter.setBrush()` to set the *fill* style/color.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`drawArc()` does not use a fill color, use [`drawEllipse()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawEllipse-5) for a full circle that is filled.

Comment: Hi, won't this cause a redraw everytime the widget comes into viewport, or user edits some other part of the widget? Won't that be ind of expensive? Isn't there a way to draw it once and for all?

Comment: The Qt paint system attempts to optimize when paint events are fired in order to reduce unnecessary repainting as much as possible and is sufficient in most cases. If a paint operation is complex or is repainted frequently, optimizations can be introduced as you mention by painting to a pixmap and caching it.

Answer (score 16):

`drawEllipse()` alone didnt solved my problem

just I added `painter.setBrush(Qt::red);`

before `drawEllipse()`

and works perfect.