# QT drawing a circle

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning QT, and had a quick question:

What would be the best way to draw a circle with radius r with the center point at x,y?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for a tutorial was just a side note, the main question was asking about the circle.

Comment: Changed it to just ask about the circle.

Comment: Oh, for what it's worth: for just drawing the circle, it look like pretty much a dupe of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9517427/179910).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a `paintEvent` use this:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawEllipse

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addEllipse

In a `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicsScene` use this:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsellipseitem.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawEllipse

The last link listed, is an overloaded method that allows you to enter the center point with the two radii specified.

`void QPainter::drawEllipse ( const QPointF & center, qreal rx, qreal ry )`

So your code would look something like:

```
// inside MyWidget::paintEvent()
painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(x,y), radius, radius);
```

Hope that helps.