# Draw a filled circle with number inside

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw a circle once not filled and when user clicks on it, it should be filled. Inside circle I want to write a single digit number.

I tried QPixmap, QLabel and some QPainterPath to make it work, but I wasn't able to do so.
How can I do that?

I need circle to be without background, only circle itself with a digit inside. Filling inside of circle will be optional, one time filled with color, one time without. Please advice.

Comment: This may help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517427/draw-a-filled-up-circle

Comment: this could be done with style sheet only (for example proper background on a button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to do by subclassing QWidget, as shown in the example code below:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

class CircleWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
   CircleWidget(int number) : _number(number), _fill(false) {/*empty*/}

   virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
   {
      e->accept();

      QPainter p(this);

      QRect r = rect();
      p.setPen(Qt::black);
      if (_fill) p.setBrush(Qt::green);
      p.drawEllipse(r);

      p.drawText(r, Qt::AlignCenter, QString("%1").arg(_number));
   }

   virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
   {
      _fill = !_fill;
      update();  // this will induce another call to paintEvent() ASAP
      e->accept();
   }

private:
   const int _number;
   bool _fill;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   CircleWidget cw(5);
   cw.resize(60,60);
   cw.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on `QGraphicsWidget`, you have to override `QGraphicsWidget::paint(QPainter *, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem const*, QWidget *)`. Make your `pressed` private member variable and change it in `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

In paint function, use `painter->setPen()` to set border and `painter->setBrush()` to set filling properties. Draw circle with `painter->drawEllipse()` and `painter->drawText()` with `QTextOption` with alignment set. You also have to override `boundingRect()` and make it return boundaries of your widget, and use that in the draw functions.

Or, if it's regular widget, override `paintEvent()`, create `QPainter` with widget as parent and draw with `size()` rectangle.

Hope it helps, give me know about the outcome.